# Как добавить простой обработчик событий onclick к элементу холста?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, javascript-events

Я  программист на Java, но  примерно за десять лет смотрю впервые на некоторые вещи, связанные с JavaScript / HTML5. Я совершенно не понимаю, того, что наверное должно быть самым простым.

В качестве примера, я просто хотел что-то нарисовать и добавить к нему обработчик событий. Я уверен, что делаю что-то глупое, но я искал повсюду, и ничего из предложенного (например, ответ на этот вопрос:
[Add onclick property to input with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789824/add-onclick-property-to-input-with-javascript) для ввода с помощью JavaScript) не работает.

Мой код ниже. Вы увидите несколько прокомментированных строк, и в конце каждой будет описание того, что не происходит или происходит.

Какой здесь правильный синтаксис?

```
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150"/>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        // elem.onClick = alert("hello world");  - displays alert without clicking
        // elem.onClick = alert('hello world');  - displays alert without clicking
        // elem.onClick = "alert('hello world!')";  - does nothing, even with clicking
        // elem.onClick = function() { alert('hello world!'); };  - does nothing
        // elem.onClick = function() { alert("hello world!"); };  - does nothing
        var context = elem.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = '#05EFFF';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);
    </script>

</body>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How do I add a simple onClick event handler to a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9880279/7394871) от участника  [@Jer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766736/jer).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/9880279/7394871

Answer (score 2):

### 2021:

Чтобы создать отслеживаемый элемент, вы должны использовать  метод [Path2D()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D).

Вы должны прослушивать события мыши на своем холсте, чтобы получить координаты курсора мыши, а затем использовать `CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath()` или `CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInStroke ()`, чтобы точно проверить, находится ли мышь над вашим элементом.

**IsPointInPath:**

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Создать окружность
const circle = new Path2D();
circle.arc(150, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circle);

// слушать события мыши
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  // Check whether point is inside circle
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(circle, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  }
  else {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  }

  // Нарисовать окружность
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fill(circle);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**IsPointInStroke:**

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Создать эллипс
const ellipse = new Path2D();
ellipse.ellipse(150, 75, 40, 60, Math.PI * .25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.lineWidth = 25;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(ellipse);
ctx.stroke(ellipse);

// Слушайте движения мыши
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  // Проверить, находится ли точка внутри обводки эллипса
  if (ctx.isPointInStroke(ellipse, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
  }
  else {
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  }

  // Рисовать эллипс
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fill(ellipse);
  ctx.stroke(ellipse);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

***Пример с несколькими элементами:***

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const circle = new Path2D();
circle.arc(50, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circle);

const circletwo = new Path2D();
circletwo.arc(200, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circletwo);

// слушать события мыши
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  // Проверить, находится ли точка внутри круга
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(circle, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fill(circle);
  }
  else {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill(circle);
  }
  
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(circletwo, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill(circletwo);
  }
  else {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill(circletwo);
  }
  
});
```

```css
html {cursor: crosshair;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

***Если у вас есть список проверяемых динамических элементов, вы можете проверять их в цикле, например:***

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var elementslist = []

const circle = new Path2D();
circle.arc(50, 75, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circle);

const circletwo = new Path2D();
circletwo.arc(150, 75, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circletwo);

const circlethree = new Path2D();
circlethree.arc(250, 75, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill(circlethree);

elementslist.push(circle,circletwo,circlethree)

document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
event = event || window.event;
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")

for (var i = window.elementslist.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){  

if (window.elementslist[i] && ctx.isPointInPath(window.elementslist[i], event.offsetX, event.offsetY)) {
document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = 'pointer';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
    ctx.fill(window.elementslist[i]);
return
} else {
document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = 'default';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    for (var d = window.elementslist.length - 1; d >= 0; d--){ 
    ctx.fill(window.elementslist[d]);
    }
}
}  

});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Источники:

[CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath)
[CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInStroke()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInStroke)

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66722289/7394871) от участника  [@Le____](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5875416/le).</sub>